# EJB Remoting over SSL

Tags: ssl, ejb, wildfly

After upgrade from WildFly-8.2, EJB remote invoke works fine on HTTP but when I set HTTPS remote connector and URL, it fails. I am invoking from a Java client using InitialContext. 
Tried adding the server certificate to java truststore and client truststore but not worked. The client shown certificate unknown.

This issue fixed when loaded the keystore from client code before remote EJB call:

```
        KeyManager[] keyManager = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        logger.info("Load JSSE truststore ");
        KeyStore trustStore = getTrustStore(userId, null);
        if (trustStore == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("A truststore is required for SSL");
        }
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManager = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(keyManager, trustManager, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

The following option passed on running java client not taken for EJB remote SSL call:
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/wf/clientw16.truststore
This way of passing truststore was working for WF-8.2.
Is this changed in WF-16 or any other settings needed?